# Inicializar un atributo de una asociación de composición

Tags: java

Estoy realizando una tarea que me han mandado y que ya tiene hecho el 'esqueleto' de lo que es el programa y solo tengo que incluir ciertos métodos. No consigo evitar un error que creo que a ojos de alguien que controle, no será nada difícil.

Ahora bien tengo dos clases: ***Player()*** y ***PlayerAttributes()***.

[image: Asociación de composición]

A continuación os adjunto el código que creo necesario para entender mi error.

Por una parte la clase ***PlayerAttributes()***:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class PlayerAttributes implements Serializable{ private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int height, speed, defense, jump, energy, ft, fg2p, fg3p, rebounds, assists;

private double weight;

public PlayerAttributes(int height, double weight, int speed, int defense, int jump, int energy,
        int ft, int fg2p, int fg3p, int rebounds, int assists) throws Exception{

    setHeight(height);
    setWeight(weight);
    setSpeed(speed);
    setDefense(defense);
    setJump(jump);
    setEnergy(energy);
    setFt(ft);
    setFg2p(fg2p);
    setFg3p(fg3p);
    setRebounds(rebounds);
    setAssists(assists);
}

//getters y setters
}
```

Y por otro la clase ***Player()***:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Player extends Person implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int number, numInternational, injuredWeeks;
private Position position;

private String imageSrc;
private PlayerAttributes attributes;

public Player(String name, String surname, String nick, LocalDate birthdate, Country country, int salary, int cancellationClause, int contractYears, Team team, int number, int numInternational, int speed, int defense, int jump, int energy, int ft, int fg2p, int fg3p, int rebounds, int assists, Position position, String imageSrc) throws Exception{

    super(name, surname, nick, birthdate, country, salary, cancellationClause, contractYears, team);        
    setNumber(number);  
    setNumInternational(numInternational);
    setPosition(position);
    setInjuriedWeeks(0);
    setImageSrc(imageSrc);

}
```

Como ya tengo declarado un atributo ***attributes*** del tipo ***PlayerAttributes***, ahora tengo que inicializarlo dentro del constructor ***Player()***:

```
attributes= new PlayerAttributes(height, weight, speed, defense, jump, energy, ft, fg2p, fg3p, rebounds, assists);
```

En la creación de un nuevo objeto de ***PlayerAttributes()*** es donde me da error, concretamente en los atributos ***height*** y ***weight***, el resto no me sale ningún error. Se puede observar que dichos atributos tampoco están incluidos en el constructor de la clase ***Player***() mientras que el resto de atributos si. En cambio en el constructor de ***PlayerAttributes()*** si que están incluidos.

¿Existe alguna forma de evitar ese error sin incluir los atributos en el constructor de ***Player()*** con el resto?

No entiendo mucho, pero creo que se me pide de esa forma, por que sino ya vendría incluido en el constructor como el resto.

Answer (score 1):

una forma de evitar ese error seria haciendo otro constructor de la clase PlayerAttributes en el que no incluya esos 2 atributos.

Algo asi:

```
public PlayerAttributes (int speed, int defense, int jump, int energy, int ft, int fg2p,
                         int fg3p, int rebounds, int assists) throws Exception {

    setSpeed(speed);
    setDefense(defense);
    setJump(jump);
    setEnergy(energy);
    setFt(ft);
    setFg2p(fg2p);
    setFg3p(fg3p);
    setRebounds(rebounds);
    setAssists(assists);
}
```

Pero si tienes que seguir 100% el esquema UML fijate que la clase Player tiene los  atributos height y weight.

Espero haberte ayudado un saludo.